# How to register sidebar wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a wordpress template and needed to register a sidebar. i used the function register_sidebar() to do it and it works but it seems to make a conflict with the default sidebar of wordpress. The default sidebar appeared as inactive. how do i register the default wordpress sidebar?

my code in functios.php

```
function wpb_init_widgets($id) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar-1',
        'id'   => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-module">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '</h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>'
    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init','wpb_init_widgets');
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean by 'default sidebar of wordpress appeared as inactive'?

Comment: @L L you know when you have a theme and you go to widgets and there is a sidebar full of widgets? that sidebar appeared as inactive and cant use it. im not very experienced with wordpress so this might be a stupid question.

Comment: Hey, it looks like `wpb_init_widgets()` is the same function that's used by the WP Bootstrap Theme: https://git.io/vy0Hq. If that's the theme you're using your quoted code on, it'll be in conflict with the existing function. Try naming it something else.

Answer (score 2):

Try editing your code like this:

```
function wpb_init_widgets_custom($id) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Customsidebar-1',
        'id'   => 'customsidebar-id',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-module">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '</h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>'
    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init','wpb_init_widgets_custom');
```

For the ID, you need to use `-id` as If you do not set the id argument value, you will get E_USER_NOTICE messages in debug mode. Also the ID sidebar-1 is taken by many themes so it might cause a conflict.
Let me know if this helped and whether the default sidebar is still inactive.
As Leland suggested, also try changing the functions name, that might be the cause of the conflict too, maybe even more likely than what I wrote above. So the new function name is changed to wpb_init_widgets_custom.

Comment: did what you sugested and the issue still on. I deleted my theme and uploaded it again with changed function and the result is the same. When i go to Appearence > Widgets, my custom sidebar is there but below the available widgets there is an incative sidebar. The message says: "this sidebar is no longer available and does not show anywhere on your site. ..." Help?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I'm making my own theme.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'function_widgets_init' );
function function_widgets_init()
{
  register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => __( 'Sidebar Widget Area', 'textdomain' ),
    'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
   ) );

 }
```